# ProcessException Error while executing /build-tools/19.1.0/aapt.exe with arguments

Tags: android, aapt, processexception

I have tried look for this error, but unluckily, no solution yet.
So need to post here.

I also tried clean / build, but still getting same error

[image]

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.iangclifton.android:floatlabel:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':aFileChooser')
    compile files('libs/LiveChatWindow.jar')
}
```

> **After Update**

```
  compileSdkVersion 25  
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" 
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'  
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file
> >     C:\my_folder\my_project\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.facebook.android\facebook\4.4.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png
> >     into
> >     C:\my_folder\my_project\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png
>
> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file
>   C:\my_folder\my_project\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.facebook.android\facebook\4.4.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png
>   into
>   C:\my_folder\my_project\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png

Comment: post your gradle in question

Comment: change buildToolsVersion '19.1.0' to buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

Comment: syn your project....

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/32neJBjjKkxQxeNRFzcxDC6